# Having issue with variable inside HTA sub

Tags: variables, vbscript, procedure, hta

I have a HTA that I want to run for four hours and pop into focus every hour as a reminder.  The problem I'm having is that there's a Sub not recognising variables more than once.  I'll post the code and then explain:

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>

<style type="text/css">
    p {font-family: 'Segoe UI Light'; font-size: 12pt}
    td {font-family: 'Segoe UI Light'; font-size: 12pt}
    input {font-family: 'Segoe UI Light'; font-size: 12pt}
    body {font-family: 'Segoe UI Light'; font-size: 12pt; color: #4D4C5C; background-color: white; background-image: url("MOEUpgrade.png")}
</style>

<TITLE>QT MOE Upgrade</TITLE>

<HTA:APPLICATION ID="MOEUpgrade"
    APPLICATIONNAME="MOE Upgrade"
    BORDER="dialog"
    SCROLL="no"
    SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
    SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
    SYSMENU="no"
    ICON="MOEUpgrade.ico">
</HEAD>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">

Dim pbTimerID, pbHTML, pbWaitTime, pbHeight, pbWidth
Dim pbBorder, pbUnloadedColor, pbLoadedColor, pbStartTime
Dim iTimerID, strProcName, strProcID

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE '%MOEUpgrade.hta%'")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each objProcess in colProcesses

    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\MDT\ProcIDs.txt")
    strProcName = objProcess.Name
    strProcID = objProcess.ProcessID
    objFile.WriteLine Now
    objFile.WriteLine strProcName & " - " & strProcID

Next

Sub Window_OnLoad

    pbWaitTime = 14400
    pbHeight = 35
    pbWidth= 760
    pbUnloadedColor="white"
    pbLoadedColor="#F69220"
    pbBorder="#4D4C5C"
    pbStartTime = Now
    rProgressbar
    pbTimerID = window.setInterval("rProgressbar", 200)

    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_VideoController WHERE AdapterDACType='Internal'")

    For Each objItem in colItems
        intHorizontal = objItem.CurrentHorizontalResolution
        intVertical = objItem.CurrentVerticalResolution
    Next

    intLeft = (intHorizontal-1024)/2
    intTop = (intVertical-600)/2
    self.resizeto 1024,600
    self.moveTo intLeft,intTop
    self.focus()
    iTimerID = window.setInterval("NagWindow",3000)

End Sub

Sub rProgressbar

    pbHTML = ""
    pbSecsPassed = DateDiff("s",pbStartTime,Now)
    pbSecsToGo = Int(pbWaitTime - pbSecsPassed)
    pbMinsToGo = Int(pbSecsToGo / 60)
    pbHrsToGo = Int(pbMinsToGo / 60)
    pbLoadedWidth = (pbSecsPassed / pbWaittime) * pbWidth
    pbUnloadedWidth = pbWidth - pbLoadedWidth

    pbHTML = pbHTML & "<table border=1 bordercolor=" & pbBorder & " cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=" & pbWidth & "><tr>"
    pbHTML = pbHTML & "<th width=" & pbUnloadedWidth & " height=" & pbHeight & "align=left bgcolor="  & pbLoadedColor & "></th>"
    pbHTML = pbHTML & "<th width=" & pbLoadedWidth & " height=" & pbHeight & "align=left bgcolor="  & pbUnLoadedColor & "></th>"
    pbHTML = pbHTML & "</tr></table>"
    pbHTML = pbHTML & "<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=" & pbWidth & "><tr>"

    Select Case TRUE

        Case pbSecsToGo <= 59
            pbHTML = pbHTML & "<td align=center width=" & pbWidth & "% height=" & pbHeight & ">" & pbSecsToGo & " seconds remaining</td>"
        Case pbSecsToGo > 60 And pbSecsToGo <= 119
            pbSecsToGo = pbSecsToGo - (pbMinsToGo * 60)
            pbHTML = pbHTML & "<td align=center width=" & pbWidth & "% height=" & pbHeight & ">" & pbMinsToGo & " minute, " & pbSecsToGo & " seconds remaining</td>"
        Case pbSecsToGo >= 120 And pbSecsToGo <= 3599
            pbSecsToGo = pbSecsToGo - (pbMinsToGo * 60)
            pbHTML = pbHTML & "<td align=center width=" & pbWidth & "% height=" & pbHeight & ">" & pbMinsToGo & " minutes, " & pbSecsToGo & " seconds remaining</td>"
        Case pbSecsToGo >= 3600 And pbSecsToGo <= 3659
            pbSecsToGo = pbSecsToGo - (pbMinsToGo * 60)
            pbMinsToGo = pbMinsToGo - (pbHrsToGo * 60)
            pbHTML = pbHTML & "<td align=center width=" & pbWidth & "% height=" & pbHeight & ">" & pbHrsToGo & " hour, " & pbMinsToGo & " minute, " & pbSecsToGo & " seconds remaining</td>"
        Case pbSecsToGo >= 3660 And pbSecsToGo <= 7199
            pbSecsToGo = pbSecsToGo - (pbMinsToGo * 60)
            pbMinsToGo = pbMinsToGo - (pbHrsToGo * 60)
            pbHTML = pbHTML & "<td align=center width=" & pbWidth & "% height=" & pbHeight & ">" & pbHrsToGo & " hour, " & pbMinsToGo & " minutes, " & pbSecsToGo & " seconds remaining</td>"
        Case pbSecsToGo >= 7200 And pbSecsToGo <= 7259
            pbSecsToGo = pbSecsToGo - (pbMinsToGo * 60)
            pbMinsToGo = pbMinsToGo - (pbHrsToGo * 60)
            pbHTML = pbHTML & "<td align=center width=" & pbWidth & "% height=" & pbHeight & ">" & pbHrsToGo & " hours, " & pbMinsToGo & " minute, " & pbSecsToGo & " seconds remaining</td>"
        Case pbSecsToGo >= 7260 And pbSecsToGo <= 10759
            pbSecsToGo = pbSecsToGo - (pbMinsToGo * 60)
            pbMinsToGo = pbMinsToGo - (pbHrsToGo * 60)
            pbHTML = pbHTML & "<td align=center width=" & pbWidth & "% height=" & pbHeight & ">" & pbHrsToGo & " hours, " & pbMinsToGo & " minutes, " & pbSecsToGo & " seconds remaining</td>"
        Case pbSecsToGo >= 10800 And pbSecsToGo <= 10859
            pbSecsToGo = pbSecsToGo - (pbMinsToGo * 60)
            pbMinsToGo = pbMinsToGo - (pbHrsToGo * 60)
            pbHTML = pbHTML & "<td align=center width=" & pbWidth & "% height=" & pbHeight & ">" & pbHrsToGo & " hours, " & pbMinsToGo & " minute, " & pbSecsToGo & " seconds remaining</td>"
        Case pbSecsToGo >= 10900
            pbSecsToGo = pbSecsToGo - (pbMinsToGo * 60)
            pbMinsToGo = pbMinsToGo - (pbHrsToGo * 60)
            pbHTML = pbHTML & "<td align=center width=" & pbWidth & "% height=" & pbHeight & ">" & pbHrsToGo & " hours, " & pbMinsToGo & " minutes, " & pbSecsToGo & " seconds remaining</td>"
        Case pbSecsToGo = 14430
            NagWindow
    End Select

    pbHTML = pbHTML & "</tr></table>"
    progressbar.InnerHTML = pbHTML

    If DateDiff("s",pbStartTime,Now) >= pbWaitTime Then
        StopTimer
        StartUpgradeTimeout
    End If

End Sub

Sub NagWindow

    objFile.WriteLine Now
    objFile.WriteLine strProcName & " - " & strProcID
    objFile.Close

End Sub

Sub StopTimer

    window.clearInterval(pbTimerID)

End Sub

Sub StartUpgradeTimeout

    self.close()

End Sub

Sub StartUpgradeNow

    If MsgBox ("Are you sure you want to start the upgrade now?",vbYesNo+vbExclamation,"Confirm Upgrade") = vbYes Then
        self.close()
    End If

End Sub

</SCRIPT>
<BODY>

    <div align="justify">
    <p>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </p>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
    <span id = "progressbar"></span>
    <br>
    <span class="tooltip" title="Press OK to start the upgrade now"><input type="button" name="OKButton" value="   OK   " onClick="StartUpgradeNow" style="font-family: 'Segoe UI Light'"></span>
     </div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The two variables in question are `strProcName` and `strProcID`, which are defined on line 28.

The `NagWindow` procedure is called on line 69.  At the moment, the interval is set to 3 seconds, but it will changed to one hour when I get it right.

Now in order to troubleshoot the issue, I'm creating a file to output the variable values.  It starts in the `For...Next` loop in lines 35-43 which creates the text file and outputs the variables `strProcName` and `strProcID` and the current time.  This bit works, as does the first iteration of the `NagWindow` Sub, where I again output the current time and variables to the same file, and then close it.

The contents of the file are as follows:

```
7/02/2018 2:14:04 PM
mshta.exe - 13916
7/02/2018 2:14:07 PM
mshta.exe - 13916
```

Interestingly, if I move the `objFile.Close` operation from line 141 so it's now outside the Sub, it only loops once before failing, i.e. like it's only correctly processing the first `objFile.WriteLine` operation on lines 40 & 41.

Eventually, I want to use the following command line inside the `NagWindow` Sub:

```
objShell.AppActivate strProcName.strProcID
```

But that's once I've figured the issues with the variables.

Comment: Please do not move the target when there are already answers addressing the problem described in your original question. If you have a new or followup question: post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You create (and open) the file at the beginning of your `<script>` block (in the global scope), but close it in the procedure `NagWindow` without ever re-opening it. Hence you try to write to an already closed file when you call `NagWindow` for the second time.

Close the file after the `For Each` loop where you create it and change

```
Sub NagWindow

    objFile.WriteLine Now
    objFile.WriteLine strProcName & " - " & strProcID
    objFile.Close

End Sub
```

into

```
Sub NagWindow
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\MDT\ProcIDs.txt", 8)
    objFile.WriteLine Now
    objFile.WriteLine strProcName & " - " & strProcID
    objFile.Close
End Sub
```

and the problem will disappear.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  I did what you suggested and the file is now empty.  I'm only using the file as a troubleshooting tool, the real issue is the NagWindow Sub being unable to recognise the strProcName and strProcID variables.

Comment: @JAG My bad. You need to re-open the file for appending. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, can you please take a look at my 'answer' and see if you can figure out what's wrong?